# Lost with Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, math, expression

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Improvedd {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int operand1 = Integer.parseInt (input.nextLine());
        char expo1 = input.next().charAt (0);
        int operand2 = Integer.parseInt (input.nextLine());
        String expression = "operand1 + expo1 + operand2";

        // how would I make it so the program ask for a math function
        // Like just let them enter 1/2 and get the printed result
        // I don't understand how I could just get the string to equal 
        // what I've placed

        System.out.println ("Enter expression: ");
        String expression = input.nextLine ();

        System.out.println (operand1 + expo1 + operand2 + "=");

        // if (expo1 == '/'  && operand2 == '0') {
        // System.out.println ("Cannot divide by zero"); }
        // how could I fix this expression

        if (expo1 == '-') {
            System.out.println (operand1-operand2);
        } else 
        if (expo1 == '+') {
            System.out.println (operand1+operand2);
        } else
        if (expo1 == '/') {
            System.out.println (operand1/operand2);
        } else 
        if (expo1 == '%') {
            System.out.println (operand1%operand2);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println ("Error.Invalid operator.");
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to pretty much do is have the enter math operation appear and just let them enter the operation be it /, %, etc, but I want them to enter it like 2/2 or 3%2 and get the printed result to be 2/2=1 or 3%2=1. The real trouble I'm having is setting the string, which I don't understand how I can set it.

Comment: Your operand2 in the out commented block is an int, so compare it with 0, not with '0' which is for chars.

Answer (score 0):

Split the input based on the operation. Use a regular expression to split on all opeartions `% * + - /`

```
String regex = "(?<=op)|(?=op)".replace("op", "[-+*/()]"); 
String[] tokens = expression.split(regex);

//The equation
System.out.println (tokens[0] + tokens[1] + tokens[2] + "=");

int operand1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int expo1 = tokens[1]
int operand2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);

//If-else ladder or the switch-case to evaluate the operation and results.
```